# how to modify a function in drupal user.module core but without touching the core?

Tags: drupal-7

I need to modify the user_save function in user.module to read like this :

```
if (empty($account->uid)) {
 // if we have a designated id, put that one in.
    if ($uww_uid){
  $account->uid =$uww_uid;
}else{
   $account->uid = db_next_id(db_query('SELECT MAX(uid) FROM {users}')->fetchField());
} 
 }
```

'
How can I do this outside of the core instead? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this in the hook_user_insert() 
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7

Simply check the $account->uid and set it to the $uww_uid you have above.

Comment: should I put this into the services module, which is the module I am using ?   but I only want to change one function within the user.module, the user_save function.  Can someone send me an example of a contributed module that uses this?

Comment: I put these two hooks in the services module as a test but get no results, can someone lead me in the right direction ? /** 
    *  Implements hook_user_insert
    */
   /**
    function services_user_insert(){
    echo "hello I'm in hook user insert in services";
 exit;
}

/** 
*  Implements hook_user_presave
*/
/**
function services_user_presave(){
    echo "hello I'm in hook user presave in services";
 exit;
}

Comment: I have implemented hook_user_presave in a contributed module, but when user gets to this line: foreach (module_implements it doesnt see it. What do I have to do to have the user module find this hook implementation? I have the hook named the same as the module . module_name_user_presave

Comment: okay, figured it out made a new module, i will upload the module shortly so others can use it.